# How to fix the "No such file or directory error" in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have an issue with opening a php file in a side folder for a project.
 I'm using

```
include('$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/KungFu/php/hours.php')
```

The error message is:

> "Warning: include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\KungFu\index.php on line 48"

also tried every variation there can be - with/out `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]`, it still is not working. The index.php is in the main folder, and in the same one in a subfolder I have the hours.php, but it is not opening it in an include statement. However it is opening it via an a tag `<a>` with `/KungFu/php/hours.php`, so I really dont udnerstand why.

Comment: `include($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/KungFu/php/hours.php');`

Comment: try relative to your current file.. `include (__DIR__.'/../KungFu/php/hours.php')` (or `include (__DIR__.'/KungFu/php/hours.php')` if i have mistaken the folder structure)

Comment: no it still doesnt work, tried all of this

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

To start, you cannot use variables inside single quotes. You can use them within double quotes. However I would suggest to use concatenation.

Also you have to put `DOCUMENT_ROOT` between single quotes because it's a key of an array (string) and not a constant. If you have error reporting enabled you should see a warning like this:

> Use of undefined constant DOCUMENT_ROOT - assumed 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
>   (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) ......

Correct example:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/KungFu/php/hours.php');
```

Knowing the path to the file is `C:\xampp\htdocs\KungFu\php\hours.php` and the path to the current file is `C:\xampp\htdocs\KungFu\index.php` you can use `dirname()` instead of the `$_SERVER` superglobal:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/php/hours.php');
```

Comment: You talk about an error, but there's no error message in your question. Please add it to your question if there is one!

Comment: "Warning: include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\KungFu\index.php on line 48"  thats the exact message im getting

Comment: All right, that's something we can work with! Please post the results of `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`. With that information we can check if the path is the right one!

Comment: string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs" this is what your code returns !

Comment: I added an example to use `dirname()`, please check!

Comment: so i place the previous statement in dirname() function ?

Comment: No just use literally like my example: `include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/php/hours.php');` the result of `dirname(__FILE__)` will be `C:/xampp/htdocs/KungFu`

Comment: Try include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] + '/KungFu/php/hours.php');

Comment: @YotamDahan `+` is not for concatenation in PHP. Other than this wrong syntax,i'ts the same as my example. So I don't see why you would post this.

Comment: @StanislavIvanov you're welcome. Please consider marking my answer as confirmed!

Comment: how to do this ?

Comment: @StanislavIvanov click the grey checkmark below the voting arrows, left of the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you directory something like this.

- app

  - index.php
  - kungfu

    - php

      - hours.php

then simple include file like this no need to add global variable

```
include "kungfu/php/hours.php";
```

Comment: index.php is in KungFu folder

Comment: Then do something like this. include "php/hours.php";